# Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 in a Intel Atom PC?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the system requirements of Ubuntu 12.10? Can I install Ubuntu on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206364/what-are-the-system-requirements-of-ubuntu-12-10-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-my-sys)

Hi my question is: Can I install Ubuntu 12.10 in a Asus Eeepc that has got 1.66 ghz (Intel Atom) and 1 gb of RAM?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum requirements are 1ghz cpu and 384 MB of RAM. However i would recommend you install 32 bit version as it should require less than the 64 bit one.(i think minimum ram there is 512 mb, but you know that these are the bare minimums).

So, go ahead.

Comment: actually, the minimum RAM is 768MB ([reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop))

Comment: Well, yes. What i gave is 12.04 minimums, so you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can install Ubuntu 12.10 in a Intel atom PC.